# Why does my Geth node "hang" and stop looking for peers after about 5 minutes?

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum

I've upgraded Geth to 1.12, completely removed my Geth DB and started syncing. Each time, the terminal hangs (stops generating new "looking for peers" entries after a few minutes. Logs look like this:

> INFO [06-20|16:39:53.461] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=23 static=0
> INFO [06-20|16:40:03.797] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=28 static=0
> INFO [06-20|16:40:13.877] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=31 static=0
> WARN [06-20|16:40:17.107] Post-merge network, but no beacon client seen. Please launch one to follow the chain!
> INFO [06-20|16:40:24.457] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=24 static=0
> INFO [06-20|16:40:34.462] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=30 static=0
> INFO [06-20|16:40:44.785] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=34 static=0
> INFO [06-20|16:40:55.123] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=34 static=0
> INFO [06-20|16:41:05.123] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=33 static=0
> INFO [06-20|16:41:15.789] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=33 static=0
> INFO [06-20|16:41:25.795] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=32 static=0
> INFO [06-20|16:41:36.123] Looking for peers                        peercount=1 tried=26 static=0
> INFO [06-20|16:41:46.123] Looking for peers                        peercount=1 tried=40 static=0
> INFO [06-20|16:41:56.130] Looking for peers                        peercount=1 tried=38 static=0
> INFO [06-20|16:42:06.130] Looking for peers                        peercount=1 tried=42 static=0
> WARN [06-20|16:42:15.529] Snapshot extension registration failed   peer=8faf3e54 err="peer connected on snap without compatible eth support"
> INFO [06-20|16:42:16.130] Looking for peers                        peercount=1 tried=38 static=0
> INFO [06-20|16:42:26.471] Looking for peers                        peercount=1 tried=36 static=0
> INFO [06-20|16:42:36.523] Looking for peers                        peercount=2 tried=39 static=0
> INFO [06-20|16:42:46.573] Looking for peers                        peercount=1 tried=39 static=0
> INFO [06-20|16:42:56.576] Looking for peers                        peercount=2 tried=35 static=0
> INFO [06-20|16:43:06.741] Looking for peers                        peercount=2 tried=39 static=0
> INFO [06-20|16:43:16.796] Looking for peers                        peercount=2 tried=34 static=0
> WARN [06-20|16:45:17.139] Beacon client online, but never received consensus updates. Please ensure your beacon client is operational to follow the chain!

My Beacon node (Prysm) connects to peers with no issue. I've checked port forwarding, firewall settings, and everything looks normal.